# Triangulated surface into 2D matrix - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, 3d, surface

I have a 3D reconstruction that is of the format: vertices and faces.
It was read in by an STL, or an OBJ file, and I believe the terminology of this surface format is triangulated.

This is nice to visualise using trisurf, however I need the representation of my surface to be a 2D matrix.

Specifically: I have a 3 column matrix named vertices, and another 3 column matrix named faces.  They do not have the same number of rows. I want a 2D matrix, where every cell in the matrix is the height of the surface.

Is this possible?  How can this be done?

Comment: What if there are more than 1 height per x, y coordinate? This is common with triangulated data

Comment: Interesting.  You can tell I am uncomfortable with triangulated data - I have never used it before.  I guess I would be happy to take some average if necessary.  The main thing, is that I have my data in a 2D matrix.

Comment: Any 3D model in a computer is a triangulated data. From Lara Croft in Tomb Raider 1 to the latest Hollywood movies, all of it are triangulated models. Average does not work. You can not take an average of a 3D model of a car. In fact, you can not describe a car with a 2D matrix. This is why triangulated models exist in fact. So either you narrow your problem (maybe your data is specific), of you rethink the entire problem again!

Comment: What you say makes complete sense.  I am sorry that I am not so familiar with triangulated data, it's obvious now you have told me that a 2 matrix can not represent a car for instance!

It turns out, that my data can be represented as a 2D matrix, since it is only a surface.  It is a dent in a metal panel.